# Tensorflow Modules in Jupiter Notebooks (using OSX)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having trouble getting tensorflow to work using Jupiter notebooks.  I am a complete noob so please keep responses as simple as possible and apologies if this is trivial.

I run the following code in the notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
```

And get this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-509396287076> in <module>()
      1 
      2 import tensorflow as tf
----> 3 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
      4 from tf_utils import load_dataset, random_mini_batches, convert_to_one_hot, predict
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

(I originally struggled to get the "import tensorflow as tf" line to work but have resolved that. The code runs fine without the second line...)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why do you want ops? You already imported tensorflow as tf. Now you can access all tensorflow related functions with tf.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you - I wasn't aware of how that worked.  Sorry if it seemed like a daft question!